# What does this JavaScript mean?

Tags: javascript, i2b2

I am working on a legacy application and all JS seems mystrious to me.
Here is the few mysterious lines which are loaded before all and I don't have any idea what they are doing.

```
var i2b2 = {sdx:{TypeControllers:{},Master:{_sysData:{}}},events:{},hive:{cfg:{},helpers:{},base_classes:{}},h:{}};  
if (undefined==i2b2.hive) { i2b2.hive = {}; }     
i2b2.hive.tempCellsList = [
        { code: "PM",
          forceLoading: true 
        },
        { code: "ONT"   },
        { code: "CRC"   },
        { code: "WORK"},
        { code: "SHRINE"},
        { code: "PLUGINMGR",
           forceLoading: true,
           forceConfigMsg: { params: [] }
        }
    ];
```

There are many more `var` and `if` statements but they are doing same thing with different variables.
Please help me to solve this mystery.

Comment: Oh dear… type coercion comparison with `undefined`. Yaiks. If you end up reusing this code, do yourself a favor and replace it with `if (typeof i2b2.hive === 'undefined') …` :)

Comment: Why the close votes for "too localized"? IMHO this is a valid question, although the poster should describe better what exactly (s)he doesn't understand.

Comment: Possible source: [i2b2_loader.js](http://informatics.kumc.edu/work/browser/i2b2-webclient/webclient/js-i2b2/i2b2_loader.js?desc=1)

Comment: @Flambino: I just had a glimpse of it and have nothing done by myself. Still will keep this in mind

Comment: Feel free to add the "i2b2" tag to this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first line initialises `i2b2` using **nested object literals**.

`var obj = {};` is a shorter way of writing `var obj = new Object();`

A simple object literal will be

```
var simpleObject = {
    property1: "Hello",
    property2: "MmmMMm",
    property3: ["mmm", 2, 3, 6, "kkk"],
    method1: function() {
        alert("my method")
    }
};
```

A nested one will be

```
var rectangle = {
    upperLeft: {
        x: 2,
        y: 2
    },
    lowerRight: {
        x: 4,
        y: 4
    }
};
```

Yours is a classic.

```
var i2b2 = {
    sdx: {
        TypeControllers: {},
        Master: {
            _sysData: {}
        }
    },
    events: {},
    hive: {
        cfg: {},
        helpers: {},
        base_classes: {}
    },
    h: {}
};
```

The second line should be IMHO

```
i2b2.hive = i2b2.hive || {};
```

This just says that if hive is undefined create a new object.

The last lines create a property `tempCellsList` to the object `hive`. ( Please note that `hive` in turn is a property of `i2b2` )
Lastly a new array of objects are added to the property `tempCellsList`

Comment: Thanks for such a detail explanation. So 'sdx:{ TypeControllers:{},Master: {_sysData: {}}}' just mean var `i2b2` and property `sdx` which have p[roperties `TypeControllers:{}` and `Master ` ?

Comment: yes. thats it. put your whole code here so that you can read it properly. http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: One thing I observed. On first line we are defining `i2b2.hive` var and on second we are checking if it is `undefined`. Does it make sense ?

Comment: no it doesn't and also you could have put the last lines on the first line itself as another property inside hive.

Answer (score 1):

This javascript code creates a variable called `ib2b` that has a number of properties: `sdx`, `events`, `hive`, etc. Those properties hold more composite objects, which are constructed below.

The idea is that this global object can be referenced from other javascript code and it stores global configuration for the client-side application.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure, what exactly you don't understand. There are two "strange" points about the code above, which I'll try to explain, but if that's not enough you will need to describe better what you don't understand:

1. The code checks is `i2b2.hive` is is undefined and set it as an empty object, if it is. Since the property is obviously set in the previous line, my guess is that this code is generated dynamically and some of the logic (such as this check) is defined in the JavaScript code even if it could (should?) be the the server side code.
2. `undefined==i2b2.hive` is a bad/wrong way to test "undefinedness", because `undefined` is not a reserved word in JavaScript.This just works, because `undefined` is just a variable that - by chance - happens to be undefined. Instead one should use `if (typeof i2b2.hive == "undefined") ...` or just `if (i2b2.hive) ...`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's setting a few parameters in that `i2b2` object. It doesn't "do" anything in itself, but it seems to set a few basic configuration settings for further execution. Try and look for similar occurrences in the code further below.

E.g it sets `i2b2.hive.tempCellList[5].forceLoading` to `true`. Later on the application probably has `if`-conditions, such as

```
for(var i in i2b2.hive.tempCellList)
{
    if(i2b2.hive.tempCellList[i].forceLoading === true)
    {
        // do something...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) It may help me in future :)